# Terminal outputting escape sequences

Tags: macos, terminal, sass, escaping

I've been using Terminal in macOS 10.12.3 to compile Sass to CSS and have been having a helluva time trying to figure out why the terminal's output is printed out with the literal escape sequences. When errors come up, it's difficult to read the output of what went wrong with all the /n's and /t's cluttering the response.

This is especially frustrating when it comes to line breaks on the directory of the file in question. I'm not new to using the command line exactly, but this is the first time since I was playing with Java years ago that I've really used it to evaluate output and this is a new problem to me.

It's not a huge thing, but I know there has to be a reason for this. Any direction would be really appreciated. Thank you V much.

[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81MM.png)

Comment: You'll get better responses with a more readable image — without background show-through, and with higher contrast of glyphs to pane.